# Using cut to remove until a delimiter from end

Tags: regex, linux, cut

I have a string with many delimiters like :

abcd - efgh - foobar.extension (Delimiter '-')

I want to remove the

```
    - foobar.extension
```

So far, I have done

```
    a='abcd - efgh - foobar.extension'
    b=`echo $a | rev | cut -d'-' -f 1 | rev`
    echo $b
```

But this does not help as it echo's

```
    foobar.extension
```

I want to be able to keep the inital part before the final delimiter('-') is found.

Comment: You specify what you want to keep with `cut` so you should use something like `cut -d'-' -f 2-` to keep everything except the first field in your existing command.  But 4 commands is a hard way of doing it.  If you don't use Bash built-in string manipulation, ``b=$(echo "$a" | sed 's/-[^-]*$//')`` deletes everything from the last dash to the end of line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash you can use this built-in string manipulation:

```
a='abcd - efgh - foobar.extension'
echo "${a% -*}"
abcd - efgh
```

`"${a% -*}"` will remove any part of `$a` starting with a space followed by `-`, from end of the string.

Or using `sed`:

```
sed 's/ *- *[^-]*$//' <<< "$a"
abcd - efgh
```

Comment: Can you explain what %-* is doing ?

Comment: Yes just added in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to select a range of fields:

```
$ echo 'abcd - efgh - foobar.extension' | cut -d'-' -f -2
abcd - efgh
```

Here, `-f -2` selects all fields up to (and including) the second field, which cuts off everything after the second delimiter.

Comment: The question says 'many delimiters' though it illustrates but two.  How do you adapt your answer to deal with more than two delimiters?

Comment: It also says "I want to be able to keep the inital part before the second delimiter('-') is found.", so that's what I'm coding against.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. But there could be many delimiters. I just want the part before the *final* delimiter.

Comment: Quick note: you can replace `-2` with `2-` for everything after the second delimiter. It is of the format `m-n`